# ITMS 90539: Invalid nested bundle – too many nested frameworks

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, watchos

I just got my first version of an app with watchOS support ready. The iOS app has 6 embedded frameworks and the watchOS 3 embedded frameworks. Upon delivering to iTunesConnect I'm cursed with the following error:

> ERROR ITMS-90539: "Invalid nested bundle. The bundle
>   Foo.app/Watch/Bar.app exceeds the maximum number of allowed nested
>   frameworks.

So three is too many? Is that slightly misleading pointing out something else wrong with my bundle or are three really too many? If so, what's the maximum?

Update: Thinking about it... perhaps they don't want *any* nested frameworks, but rather want me to put the watchOS-frameworks in the Frameworks folder of the container iOS-App? In that case the default extension rpath `../../Frameworks` would make sense as well. Now comes the next problem then... how am I supposed to deal with cross-platform frameworks then? They are having the same name here hence I can't put them all into the same Frameworks folder :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Further experimentation led me to find the reason, which I leave here in case someone stumbles over the same problem:

ITMS-90539 can happen in an iOS/watchOS project, when you embed the frameworks relative to the watchOS app as opposed to the watchOS extension. Fixing this made the validation pass.

Comment: Thanks, this probably saved me hours of hair pulling

Comment: I can't understand this, Could you please explain more? - What should I do exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the target settings and try to remove embedded frameworks from `"WatchApp target"` and leave those frameworks in the `"WatchExtension" target`.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer with more description or screenshot.